# Dialogflow - Phone Number Specification (@sys.phone-number)

Tags: format, entity, dialogflow-es, specifications, phone-number

In Dialogflow, when using @sys.phone-number as an entity type, what specification is the query expected to follow in order for part of it to be mapped to that entity parameter?

Suppose I have an entity called generic_phone_number with the entity type being @sys.phone number. 1 (800) 555-6666, (647) 888-9999, and 5556667777 do get parsed correctly, but not 555.666.7777.

For numbers that don't follow the specification, can Dialogflow itself parse them to formats that the entity will hold them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take the help of Regex as shown in [this example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-regex-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js). You can set a pattern and in the webhook check if the number matches your requirement else ask for input again. You may also be required to capture this using @sys.any or some other combinations.